# Show $\lim\limits_k \int_{A_k} f_k = \lim\limits_k\int_A f_k,\;$ given $f_k \in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n),\; \lim\limits_k\lambda(A_k\Delta A) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Show $\lim\limits_k \int_{A_k} f_k = \lim\limits_k\int_A f_k,\;$ given $f_k \in\mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n),\; \lim\limits_k\lambda(A_k\Delta A) = 0$. Here $\{A_k\}$ and $A$ are Lebesgue measurable. And if needed, $\lim\limits_k\int_A f_k < \infty.$

What I have so far:
$$
\left|\int_{A_k}f_k - \int_Af_k\right| = \left|\int(\chi(A_k)-\chi(A))f_k\right| \le \int |(\chi(A_k)-\chi(A))f_k| = \int \chi(A_k\Delta A)|f_k|
$$

I'm trying to show $\int \chi(A_k\Delta A)|f_k| \to 0$ but of no avail.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: If you assume $|f_{k}|$ are bounded almost everywhere does it help in controlling the size of the term on the far right of your inequality?

Comment: @akech Yes, that would help me finish the proof.

Comment: Doesn't integrability of $f_{k}$ give you that?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Here is a fact about integrability that you could use.
Given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta$ such that

$$
\int_A |f_{k}(x)|\lambda(dx) \;\;<\;\;\epsilon
$$

whenever $\lambda(A) < \delta$.

There exists $N$ so large such that $\lambda (A_{k} \Delta A) < \delta$ for all $k > N$.

Comment: The problem is that $\delta$ only works for one $f_k$. I need it to work for all $f_k$ with sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: Can we not take the max of all such deltas $\delta_{1}, ..., \delta_{k}$?